# Evaluating $\int{ \frac{\arctan\sqrt{x^{2}-1}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+x}}} \,dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

How to integrate?
$$\int{ \frac{\arctan\sqrt{x^{2}-1}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+x}}}\, dx$$

I have no idea how to do it.
Tried to get some information from wiki, but its too hard :|

Comment: Please try to use a more specific title, this one is very generic and will not assist users searching for similar queries in future.

Comment: It's easier for people if you use conventional letters for variables. Since only one variable appears in your question, it would be more friendly to call it $x$. The letter $n$ normally denotes an integer.

Comment: The substitution $n=\sec\theta$ looks messy.  I've also gotten it into the form $\int\frac{\cos^{-1}xdx}{x\sqrt{x+1}}$ and tried integration by parts, but that doesn't seem to lead anywhere as eliminating the inverse trig function still leaves natural log terms...

Comment: @user51402 looks like Wolfram Mathematica [refuses symbolic integration](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=\[Integral]ArcTan[Sqrt[-1+%2B+n^2]]%2FSqrt[n+%2B+n^2]+\[DifferentialD]n).

Comment: Hope you are not randomly writing integrands and asking us. And now I realize I just brought up an old question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the integral 
$$\int\! \frac{\arccos x}{x\sqrt{x+1}} \, \mathrm{d}x,$$

which was derived by Mike. Using the property $\arccos x = \frac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin x$, we have

$$=\frac{\pi}{2}\int\! \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x\sqrt{x+1}}-\int\! \frac{\arcsin x}{x\sqrt{x+1}} \, \mathrm{d}x.$$

The leftmost integral is evaluated trivially and so we consider the rightmost integral. We express $1/\sqrt{x+1}$ in terms of its MacLaurin series, valid for $|x|<1,$

$$\int \! \frac{\arcsin x}{x} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {-\frac{1}{2} \choose k} x^k \, \mathrm{d}x$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {-\frac{1}{2} \choose k}\int\! x^{k-1}\arcsin x \, \mathrm{d}x.$$

Then, upon consideration of the integral

$$\int \! x^{k-1}\arcsin x\, \mathrm{d}x,$$

and an application of integration by parts, we find that

$$\int \! x^{k-1}\arcsin x\, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{x^k}{k}\arcsin x - \frac{1}{k}\int \! \frac{x^k \, \mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}. $$

According to Mathematica, the remaining integral may be expressed in terms of the hypergeometric function. This procedure may or may not provide an evaluation for $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 1):

Putting $n=\sec\theta$ gives $$I=\int \frac{\theta \sec\theta \tan\theta}{\sec\theta\sqrt{\cos \theta+1}}\ d\theta=\int\frac{\theta\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}{\sqrt{\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}}\ d\theta$$ Substituting $\cos\theta/2$ by $x$ gives $$I=-2\int\frac{\cos^{-1}x}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}dx$$ where $a^2=1/2$. This does not seem to have any better form, at least as an indefinite integral.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica returns a closed form solution for $\displaystyle\int\frac{\cos^{-1}x\,dx}{x\sqrt{x+1}}$, but it is several dozen lines long.  I am not sure how to clean it up yet.

Comment: The solution you speak of can be reduced to the size of a single screen (six or seven lines) if *FullSimplify* is employed.

Comment: Please show the amazing result.